# What's wrong with this code

Tags: c++, strcpy

Somebody told me that this piece of code has some serious issues but I have not been able to get my head around such issues. Can you guys please educate me on this?

```
static char BASED_CODE szFilter[] = "HTML Files (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*||";

const char* filter = "HTML Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files (*.*)|*.*||";
size_t length = strlen(filter);
strcpy_s(szFilter, length + 1, filter);
```

Comment: If you're really using C++, consider also using C++ strings.

Comment: What is BASED_CODE? String literals have type `const char*`.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the code asserts that .xls and .xlsx extensions are used for HTML files is another problem!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the buffer overrun leaps out at me – `szFilter` isn't big enough to receive `filter`.

Why not use `std::string` since you are using C++?  That makes these issues vanish.

Comment: +1 for a funny way to state the (not so) obvious (one could easily miss the *.xlsx vs. *.xls)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`strcpy_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.80).aspx) should be the size of the *destination* buffer; you've given it the size of the input string.

But as you're working in C++, you should avoid `strcpy()` (etc.) entirely, and use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

`szFilter` is shorter than `filter`, so there is not enough place to copy `filter` to `szFilter`. You current code has undefined behaviour.